# Gitlab CI - Failed to register runner

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-8

I've setup my gitlab installation from source, secured it with letsencrypt and deployed it under `https://gitlab.mydomain.com`. I can access the website and create repositories, etc. but I can't find a way to register a gitlab ci runner for the installation.

```
Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/ci):
https://gitlab.mydomain.com/ci
Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner:
xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx
Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner:
[server]: test
Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):
test
ERROR: Registering runner... failed     runner=xxxxxxx 
status=couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab.mydomain.com/ci/api/v1/runners/register.json:
Post https://gitlab.mydomain.com/ci/api/v1/runners/register.json: 
read tcp [ipv6address]:33518->[ipv6address]:443: read: connection reset by peer
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

My gitlab system is working fine and I really ran out of explanations why there would be a `connection reset by peer`. When I try to curl the address from the error message directly, it returns a correct response.

```
curl -v https://gitlab.mydomain.com/ci/api/v1/runners/register.json
*   Trying ipv6address...
* Connected to gitlab.mydomain.com (ipv6address) port 443 (#0)
* found 174 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 700 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*        server certificate verification OK
*        server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*        common name: mydomain.com (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: RSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: CN=mydomain.com
*        start date: Wed, 18 May 2016 14:35:00 GMT
*        expire date: Tue, 16 Aug 2016 14:35:00 GMT
*            issuer: C=US,O=Let's Encrypt,CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*        compression: NULL
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
> GET /ci/api/v1/runners/register.json HTTP/1.1
> Host: gitlab.mydomain.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< Server: nginx
< Date: Sun, 29 May 2016 09:14:09 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 2
< Connection: keep-alive
< Allow: OPTIONS, POST
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Status: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

Comment: Could you post your runner config?

Comment: @HuiWang - It only has 1 line `concurrent = 1`. I assume this is because the process of creating a config fails with the above error.

Comment: Please have a look at this link https://gitlab.com/wiget/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/tls-self-signed.md

Comment: @HuiWang - I don't understand which certificate from letsencrypt I have to store at the requested location. I tried with copying my `fullchain.pem` to `/etc/gitlab-runner/gitlab.mydomain.com.crt` but the error still occurs. When I use `--debug` it says `Trying to load /etc/gitlab-runner/certs/gitlab.mydomain.com.crt ... ` but nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem went away after updating gitlab to `8.8.3` and `gitlab-multi-ci-runner` to the most recent version.

I also started my gitlab nginx configuration files from scratch.

In the end, I can't tell which change exactly solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the runner and gitlab are running on the same host you can get around this problem by entering a the first question the following instead what is given in the docs:

```
http://gitlab:port
```

where **gitlab** is the container name and **port** the left port number of the container. If you are using gitlab internal ssl certs you specify https instead of http. This always solves this problem when I get it.

Answer (score 1):

For those that are using docker:

The issue its about docker network.

If you try

```
  "$docker container inspect $id"
```

You are going to see the IPAddress of gitlab container.

Point to that ip adress on first question to works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had so far many errors and issue starting with Error 404, 403 and endings with problem with post request.

For me, problem seems to be [incompatibility between GitLab and ci-runner](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/2275).

Solution, same on post issue, was install older version of ci-runner:

`sudo apt install gitlab-ci-multi-runner=1.11.1`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work for me still getting error ``ERROR: Registering runner... failed   runner=pcT3WTf5 status=couldn't execute POST against 
http://gitlab.com/api/v4/runners: 
Post https://gitlab.com:443/api/v4/runners: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority  
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems``

Comment: In your case it looks like HTTPS and certificate issue. Use some trusted authority (like Lets encrypt) or manually add CA you used for sign the certificate as trusted.

This should be helpful https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by installing `gitlab-ci-multi-runner=1.11.1`.